# Securing form in JavaScript

Tags: php, forms, security

What is the best way process form fields before passing to payment processors?
For example, lets say I have a form that have a hidden price field, which is the value that will be passed to PayPal, in this case the user can easily change the value using firebug and pass any value to paypal.
I usually pass values from the database to PayPal using PHP, but I am just anxious to know what other ways are available to deal with this.

Youssef

Comment: You ALWAYS have to assume, from the server side, that the client side can't be trusted.

Comment: you check the price paypal passes back to you

Comment: PayPal should give you the option to create an almost fixed price inventory item you can reference and pass that of in lieu of an actual price.  Then the user can't modify the cost.  The form you're describing sounds like the "donate" API where they get to chose the amount. And, as others have mentioned,  check the processed payment amount when you receive the response back to confirm they're paying all they need to.

Comment: So from the answers I got I think the best way is to use server side and check price paypal passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEVER trust client side input. You may use Javascript or simple HTML or anything, the point is, with enough knowledge (and determination), users can and will always be able to change anything on client side and post it.

I'd always pass such inputs from server-side.

Now one way is to have a "checksum" hidden field inside your form which stores the amount value hashed (along with a secret 'key') which is posted to and validated by your server. Or, simply validating individual fields on server once your form is posted and further redirecting the user to PayPal (along with POST parameters).

Or, another way (rather time consuming but bullet-proof and the "industry standard" of verifying validity of a transaction) is to see what PayPal reports back to your server after the transaction is completed (i.e. the amount of transaction obtained via [PayPal Instant Payment Notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)) and then handling the response on your server.

Additionally, specific to your question (Paypal Payments Standard buttons), here is some great advice from PayPal:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/

Comment: your "Or, another way" is the only *correct* way in the world of eccomerce

Comment: Haha, well said @dagon.

Comment: Agree with Dagon too. Definitely keep using server side!!! and now thanks to Akshay Sharma handling the response from PayPal.